# Save once checkbox value already inside another loop

Tags: php, loops, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if(isset($_POST['sharks'])) {
      $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['sharks'];
  } else {
      $_SESSION['value'] = '';
  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <?php
  echo '<input name="sharks" type="checkbox" value="1" id="sharks" ';
    if ($_SESSION['value'] == 1) {
      echo ' checked="checked"';
    }
  echo ">";
  ?>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Salva</button>
</form>
```

I'm already inside a loop of users, I just want to add a checkbox next to them and save the value of that checkbox connected to that user. 
[image]


When I try to save the checkbox this is what happen: 
[image]

Thank you all

UPDATE:
This image can help a lot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILbSm.png

This is the table I have, I just want to add a checkbox next to every user and save the status of them.

Comment: explain question briefly...

Comment: you got multiple checkboxes but they got the same name, you should use `sharks[]` as name.
So in PHP `$_POST['sharks']` is an array with keys `0,1...x`

Comment: Is input names for all your check boxes are unique?

Comment: @Alexandre Painchaud, she still don't make it clear in her question.

Comment: @Elle, in case of unique check boxes you have to wrap your code with `foreach` loop.

Comment: @OptimisticWalker sure

Comment: sorry guys, maybe my code is bad written or bad explained. Anyway, I want to add and save a checkbox value ("checked" or "unchecked") next to every user in the admin table I have. But when I saved the checkbox value of the first user, it save all the checkbox values of the others users, because already inside a loop... @DhanuK (and the other guys)

Comment: @OptimisticWalker Yes I wat thinking the same but I don't know how to set it :(

Comment: I have updated my question with a helpful screenshot

Comment: @Elle, post your php and html code for at least 3 check boxes.

Comment: @OptimisticWalker this is my code there is no more code I have done. The other code is already done by others. but I have noticed that I'm inside a form... maybe the "submit" action affects all the checkboxes when I submit mine.
anyway the other code is just a loop of users in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make an answer based on assumption. I assume that your field names are identical. In general, in case of identical input names either all values shall be checked at once when you select one or only one value shall be checked based on conditional submit. This is usual as you are not defining unique input names for the users. However, In order to select as much users as you need follow the code structure below:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $_SESSION['mysession'] = $_POST; }else{ $_SESSION['mysession'] = array('user1'=>'', 'user2'=>'', 'user2'=>'', 'user3'=>'');}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="user1" value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['user1'])){ echo "checked";}?> > 
<input type="checkbox" name="user2" value="2" <?php if (isset($_POST['user2'])){ echo "checked";}?> > 
<input type="checkbox" name="user3" value="3" <?php if (isset($_POST['user3'])){ echo "checked";}?> > 
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Try</button>
</form>
 
<?php var_dump($_SESSION['mysession']); ?>
```

If you need to insert the value `1` into database for all users just change the value to `value="1"` for every check box input.

So you don't not need separate save button for every check box. I hope that you shall definitely get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is can help you basically:

```
<?php

$selected_attribute = $_SESSION['value'] == 1 ? "checked" : "";
echo("<input name='sharks' type='checkbox' value='1' id='sharks' ".$selected_attribute.">");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it returns me "0". See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/gMLMPkt.png

Comment: I have updated my question with a helpful screenshot ;)

Comment: Nice one but when I set the status to checked and reload the page, the status not stay checked :(

Comment: Because you need to set `$_SESSION['value'] = 1;` when you select it

Comment: No problem and check my edit: code improved so you can use like that.

Answer (score 1):

Tried improving/cleaning your code a bit:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['sharks'])) {
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['sharks'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['value'] = '';
} ?>

<form action="" method="POST">

    <input name="sharks" type="checkbox" value="1" id="sharks" <?php echo $_SESSION['value'] == 1 ? "checked" : ""; ?>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Salva</button>
</form>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks to have cleaned it. Anyway works but when I save the status with the button, all the checkbox are checked :( remember I'm already in a loop, maybe the "submit" action affects all the checkboxes

Comment: @Elle If you are in a loop, then firstly you should not use `ID` attribute a static value. Secondly, to counter this problem, you need to save something more *unique* in you session value.
Or, you can try this: Store all the checked check boxes value in the ** value session** and then use `in_array` to check if the value of checkbox is saved in the session. 
Hope it made sense.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try, dont worry. Thanks anyway for all :)

Comment: @Elle, Don't count the down vote.  It's just a virtual life. Keep coming to find your own way. There are many enlightened users here too who don't think that down voting is their only business that makes them credible. My up vote goes for you. Although it doesn't make any difference.